# how to refresh token servicestack typescript

Tags: servicestack, jwt

On servicestack it says that for regular client it should be like that but for typescript it should be somehow different. Anyone knows how to do it?

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
client.OnAuthenticationRequired = () => {
    client.BearerToken = authClient.Send(new Authenticate()).BearerToken;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `onAuthenticationRequired` and `refreshToken` was added to the TypeScript [servicestack-client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client) in **v0.0.32** where they can be used to transparently handle **401 Unauthorized** Responses and re-authenticate the `JsonServiceClient` from within the callback before it automatically retries the original failed request:

#### Transparently handle 401 Unauthorized Responses

If the server returns a **401 Unauthorized** Response either because the client was Unauthenticated or the configured Bearer Token or API Key used had expired (or was invalidated), you can use `onAuthenticationRequired` callback to re-configure the client before automatically retrying the original request, e.g:

```
client.onAuthenticationRequired = async () => {
    const authClient = new JsonServiceClient(authBaseUrl);
    authClient.userName = userName;
    authClient.password = password;
    const response = await authClient.get(new Authenticate());
    client.bearerToken = response.bearerToken;
};

//Automatically retries requests returning 401 Responses with new bearerToken
var response = await client.get(new Secured());
```

#### Automatically refresh JWT Tokens

With the [Refresh Token support in JWT](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#refresh-tokens) you can use the `refreshToken` property to instruct the Service Client to automatically fetch new JWT Tokens behind-the-scenes before automatically retrying failed requests due to invalid or expired JWTs, e.g:

```
//Authenticate to get a new Refresh Token
const authClient = new JsonServiceClient(authBaseUrl);
authClient.userName = userName;
authClient.password = password;
const authResponse = await authClient.get(new Authenticate());

//Configure client with RefreshToken
client.refreshToken = authResponse.RefreshToken;

//Clients will automatically retrieve new JWT Tokens as needed
var response = await client.get(new Secured());
```

#### Send Refresh Tokens to an alternate server

Use the `refreshTokenUri` property when refresh tokens need to be sent to a different ServiceStack Server that issues new JWT Tokens, e.g:

```
client.refreshToken = refreshToken;
client.refreshTokenUri = authBaseUrl + "/access-token";
```

Comment: thanks for response. really need refresh token asap. but seems like v0.0.31 is not in working state. some imports is missing, Headers, Response, Request. Could you please look at it

Comment: @Roman they're all W3C fetch definitions, you either need recent version of TypeScript with es2016 lib dependency or you need to install @types/whatwg-fetch